# Git - Switch branch while doing git rebase

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree (Version 1.9.13.7) as GUI for Git on Windows 10. Today, when I was trying to rebase a feature branch to master branch. At some point of rebasing, it seemed to me that the rebase is done because I saw clearly that the feature branch's head commit had been highlighted with bold circle on it on SourceTree. Then I managed to switch to master branch. So I started to merge the feature branch to master. What happened to me then was that it started to rebase again. I didn't suspect this at that time so just continued to rebase. After that is done, I realized that I only had last 3 commits on both master and feature branch. And the rest of commits were lost.

Luckily I could go to the feature branch and use *git cherry-pick* for range of commits from command line to recover all the lost commits. Basically what it did was checkout the original commit and rebase it on feature branch.

So this gave me huge lesson for doing rebase. But I am still confused about many things that happened:

1. Why did git allow me to switch to master branch while rebasing? In my case, it could be the problem of SourceTree UI which didn't update correctly. It made me think that the rebase was done. So I went for switching to master. But why does git allow this in the first place?
2. If we are allowed to switch branch during rebasing, should git take it as "cancel rebase" so that the feature branch should go back to what it was before rebasing? Why did it basically just get rid of all my previous commits.

Comment: SourceTree for Windows or OS X or ?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Windows 10

Comment: SourceTree for Windows (I can't testify how it is on other platforms) is horribly broken because of its asynchronous UI. The UI tends to light up and make commands available to you before it has stabilized its internal data structures, as such it is entirely possible and reproducible to switch branches and do pulls and merges before SourceTree has caught up and then does the wrong thing. I recommend you find another tool than SourceTree.

Comment: As an example, try this: Double-click on a different branch, up pops a progress bar telling you its checking out that branch, immediately when this popup disappears and you can click the Pull button, do so, you should notice that it will now default to pulling from the upstream of the previous branch, into the new current branch. This is **bad**.

Comment: As a possible answer to a follow-up question on "Which UI to use then?" the best answer is possibly: "None". Adapt your PS1 in git shell to show current status and use UI only to check the structure of the repository.